# kvm Bridge issue - no network to guest

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge

I currently have a Proxmox (debian) KVM host running multiple OpenVZ Containers for general usage,
I am looking at creating a KVM VM however I'm unable to get networking to work for the CentOS KVM Guest.

please find network configuration from Host:

```
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          inet6 addr: fe80::22cf:30ff:fe19:7b67/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:41861518 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:23326041 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:16692957938 (xx.x GiB)  TX bytes:16624094064 (xx.x GiB)
          Interrupt:47 Memory:fbfe0000-fc000000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1805386 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1805386 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:532155476 (507.5 MiB)  TX bytes:532155476 (507.5 MiB)

vmbr0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          inet addr:88.xxx.xxx.229  Bcast:88.xxx.xxx.xxx  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::22cf:30ff:fe19:7b67/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:38116128 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21500108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:15771625496 (xx.x GiB)  TX bytes:16504698806 (xx.x GiB)
```

and Route from host:

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask           Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
88.xxx.xxx.109  0.0.0.0         255.xxx.xxx.xxx   UH    0      0        0 venet0
88.xxx.xxx.0    0.0.0.0         255.xxx.xxx.xxx   U     0      0        0 vmbr0
0.0.0.0         88.xxx.xxx.1    0.0.0.0           UG    0      0        0 vmbr0
```

From the guest CentOS KVM VM:

```
#ifconfig
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
              inet addr:88.xxx.xxx.252  Bcast:88.xxx.xxx.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::22cf:30ff:fe19:7b67/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:38116128 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:21500108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
              RX bytes:15771625496 (xx.x GiB)  TX bytes:16504698806 (xx.x GiB)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
              RX packets:1805386 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:1805386 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
              RX bytes:532155476 (507.5 MiB)  TX bytes:532155476 (507.5 MiB)
```

Routes from Guest:

```
#route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway       Genmask        Flags Matric  Ref   Use  Iface
88.xxx.xxx.0    0.0.0.0       255.255.252.0  U     0       0     0    eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0       255.255.0.0    U     0       0     0    eth0
0.0.0.0         88.xxx.xxx.1  0.0.0.0        UG    0       0     0    eth0
```

a ping from the host to the guest is coming back with:

```
# ping 88.xxx.xxx.252
PING 88.xxx.xxx.xxx (88.xxx.xxx.252) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 88.xxx.xxx.229 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 88.xxx.xxx.229 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 88.xxx.xxx.229 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
--- 88.208.236.252 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3016ms
```

Any help would be grealy appreciated!

**EDIT**
Sorry forgot to include brctl output

```
# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
vmbr0           8000.20cf30197b67       no              eth0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not that knowledgeable on KVM, but based on what I know to be true for Xen it would seem that you're missing an interface on your bridge - you only have your physical host interface there, but it should also list whatever network device your guest is using on the host. I see a venet0 interface mentioned on the host's routing table, can you please replace the ifconfig with a ifconfig -a?

If venet0 turns out to be the guest's interface, you should probably add it to the bridge using `brctl addif vmbr0 venet0`. Keep in mind though that the routing table shows that the host thinks the IP "on the other side" of the link to be .109, so you may have a configuration issue right there if it turns out that's the right interface. Though deleting the route through venet0 should be enough if it belongs to the bridge.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the Input, Marked question as correct after reading your comment I noticed that you where correct that there was an interface missing from the bridge. After shutting down the guest and starting (not a reboot) the additional interface appeared within the bridge and networking was successfull when Guest Booted!!   Thank you very much!